# Plot using NSolve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

```
NSolve[ - 8 a^2 x + 9 x^2 -12 x^3 + 4 x^4 == 0, x];
Plot[Evaluate[  x   /.   %  ],    {a, -0.6, 0.6}]
```

**How can I show only positive roots in this plot?**

This equation is one of the case of Equation (32) given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0611110.pdf).

Comment: Hello again. It's really a good ideas to start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. I have edited your question for you this time.

Comment: If you want to *clarify* the question, please edit the original question, not one of the answers.  If you want to ask about a *new* problem (even if related to this one), please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) is for finding numerical solutions and is not appropriate when there are non-numerical parameters, such as `a` in your example.  Use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) instead.

If you only need a plot, an alterative approach to solve-and-plot is to plot the implicit equation directly using [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html).

```
ContourPlot[-8 a^2 x + 9 x^2 - 12 x^3 + 4 x^4 == 0,
 {a, -.6, .6}, {x, -1, 3},
 FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{a, x}, x > 1*^-16]]
```

[image]

[`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) and [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) are used to increase accuracy. [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) is to eliminate non-positive solutions.  Since `x == 0` is always a solution, I needed to use a value marginally higher than 0 to define the region and exclude the `x == 0` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  x /. NSolve[
    {
     -8 a^2 x + 9 x^2 - 12 x^3 + 4 x^4 == 0
     , x > 0
     }
    , x
    , Reals
    ]
  ]
 , {a, -0.6, 0.6}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for this help.